# Object detection with using keras: which R-CNN models is best?(recognition the navigations symbols)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm doing a project these days.
Goal of this project is approximately 200 symbol recognition.
Symbols are using in the navigation(turn_right, turn_left etc..)

I'm using YOLO model now
For traning this models, I thought I needed some improvement about traning speed.
This program will using when testing new navigation.

Is there any better models?
The model needs very fast traning speed, and high accuracy

Answer (score 1):

Yolo is one of the best object detection for real time detection.  Fast Training and high accuracy are competing goals. Did you mean test speed (with a trained model)?

Anyway, if you need fast training I highly suggest the cyclical learning rate strategy [proposed](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.09820) by Leslie N. Smith.

Yolo has different version, so take a look at that as well.